# When scoring in Prosperity, is there a maximum limit for research?

Tags: prosperity

In [Prosperity](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/145203/prosperity), the rules for scoring Research say:

> **Research**: each player moves a number of spaces in both Research tracks equal to the number of Research symbols visible on their
>   individual board. For each track, the player with the highest marker
>   scores 3 Prosperity points, the second player scores 1 point. In case
>   of a tie for the first place, all leading players gain 2 points (and
>   no points are awarded for second place).

The Prosperity board has only a [limited number of spaces](http://boardgamegeek.com/image/1873210/prosperity) on the two Research tracks. What happens if during scoring a player reaches the end of the track? Do they count the 'extra' steps for the purpose of determining first place, or would several players at the end of the track each be tied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [the official answer](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1067044/top-of-the-research-tracks) on BGG:

> The space with the magnifying glass is the top space, and you cannot move beyond it. If more than one player reaches the top space, they are tied.

Comment: Yup that's correct, though i have to ask... don't you find Prosperity suffers from Monopoly syndrome? i.e. Buy up all the cards that award Prosperity points, and you can't lose!

Comment: @MK78 - I haven't found that. Obviously those cards are crucial, but it's the timing that matters most. You can't just buy Prosperity symbols and ignore research or ecology, for example.